# Regex expression that match any letters between words, OR if there's no letter at all

Tags: regex

Can you help me to build a regex that allows me to match:

```
servicerequestinfo
service requestinfo
service and requestinfo
serviceand requestinfo
service andrequestinfo

servicerequest info
servicerequest and info
servicerequest andinfo
servicerequestand info

service without     request   and   info
service       request      info
```

the most important thing is I can find the word "service", "request", and "info" in one line. But the only thing that's working for me that I can found on the internet is just:

```
service(\w*)request(\w*)info
service (\w*)request(\w*)info
service(\w*) request(\w*)info
```

or it's variation, which, as far as I know, can only match some of them, but not all of them. I tested variety of them using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and I now have run out of ideas. Regex is something new to me, and I'm learning by doing. But it's just very hard to wrote google search query that can pinpoint me to the correct information about the question I currently have about regex. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following Regex...

```
service[\w\s]*request[\w\s]*info
```

Good Luck!